# How to inner join the WRITES table and the BOOK table?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to inner join the WRITES table and the BOOK table. In order to receive an authorID when the page task8.htm submits. After the submission the task8.php which is what you are looking at now, should extract the bookID, booktitle, ISBN fields for all books written by that authorID. I am having trouble inner joining the tables right now.

I have tried inner joining the tables using SELECT bookID, booktitle, quantity,name, region FROM BOOK INNER JOIN WRITES ON BOOK.bookID = WRITES.bookID ORDER BY booktitle, quantity, name;";.

```
 <?php  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookstore");
 if ( !$conn ) {  die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error()); }
 $sqlPUBLISHER = "SELECT bookID, booktitle, quantity,name, region FROM 
BOOK INNER JOIN PUBLISHER ON BOOK.publishID = PUBLISHER.publishID ORDER 
BY booktitle, quantity, name;";
 $resultsPUBLISHER = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlPUBLISHER) or die ('Problem 
with query' . mysqli_error());
 ?>
 <h1>Publisher table</h1>
 <table> <tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Region</th>
 </tr> <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsPUBLISHER)) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["name"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["region"]?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php }
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?> </table>
 <?php $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookstore");
 if ( !$conn ) { die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error()); }
 $sqlWRITES = "SELECT bookID, booktitle, quantity,name, region FROM BOOK 
INNER JOIN WRITES ON BOOK.bookID = WRITES.bookID ORDER BY booktitle, 
quantity, name;";
 $resultsWRITES = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlWRITES) or die ('Problem with 
query' . mysqli_error());
 ?>
 <h1>Writes table</h1>
 <table> <tr>
 <th>Book ID</th>
 </tr> <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsWRITES)) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["bookID"]?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php }
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?> </table>
  <?php $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookstore");
 if ( !$conn ) { die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error()); }
 $sqlBOOK = "SELECT bookID, booktitle, quantity,name, region FROM BOOK 
INNER JOIN WRITES ON BOOK.bookID = WRITES.bookID ORDER BY booktitle, 
quantity, name;";
 $resultsBOOK = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlBOOK) or die ('Problem with 
query' . mysqli_error());
 ?>
 <h1>Book table</h1>
 <table> <tr>
  <th>Book title</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 </tr> <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultsBOOK)) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["booktitle"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["quantity"]?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php }
 mysqli_close($conn);
 ?> </table>
```

Comment: I made a few changes. $sqlBOOK = "SELECT bookID, booktitle, ISBN FROM BOOK JOIN WRITES ON BOOK.bookID = WRITES.bookID WHERE authorID = ". $author . ";";

Comment: And I also used $author = $_GET['authorID']

Comment: The full block of code is like: <?php 
 $author = $_GET['authorID']
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookstore");
 if ( !$conn ) { die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error()); }
 $sqlBOOK = "SELECT bookID, booktitle, ISBN FROM BOOK JOIN WRITES ON BOOK.bookID = WRITES.bookID WHERE authorID = ". $author . ";";
 $resultsBOOK = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlBOOK) or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());
  ?>

Comment: I fixed my syntax, I have the right quotations and the semicolon added in now.

Comment: <?php 
 $author = $_GET["authorID"];
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bookstore");
 if ( !$conn ) { die("Connection failed: " .mysqli_connect_error()); }
 $sqlWRITES = "SELECT bookID, booktitle, ISBN FROM BOOK JOIN WRITES ON BOOK.bookID = WRITES.bookID WHERE authorID = ". $author . ";";
 $resultsWRITES = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlWRITES) or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());
 ?>

Comment: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\task8.php on line 31
Problem with query

Comment: That is my error message. Any tips?

Comment: You have to pass the $con to mysqli_error($con), or it doesn't know where to pull the error message from.

Answer (score 0):

If there are columns of the same name that exist in both tables, you need to specify that in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT BOOK.bookID, booktitle, quantity,name, region
```